# Is there any away to randomize a display message in rules?

Tags: 7, rules

I would like to disable drupal's standard message when a new node has been saved and then via Rules (or any other recommendations) provide a pool of random messages to be displayed to the end user when a node is then saved. They will essentially say the same thing, but just in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

The display message can be customized by following [this procedure](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7#comment-23023). You might also want to write a [custom module](http://drupal.org/node/1074360), which may enable you to control your message display by user role.

If you want to display the status message in a different way, (there is a module for that ;-) too) try [Better Messages](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) module.

> Better Messages is a very simple module that provides "Popup-like" Drupal messages.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1: Disable Messages module

You could use the [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module to "*disable Drupal's standard message*" (as in your question). Here is a quote from its project page:

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users. However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out messages shown to the end users.

Some of its features are:

> - Filter out messages that match a full text string exactly.
> - Filter out messages that match a regular expression.
> - Permissions to specifically hide all messages of a given type from any role.
> - Disable all filtering for specific users.
> - Disable all filtering for specific paths.
> - Apply filtering only for specific paths.
> - Debug system to get messages in the HTML without showing it to the end users.

#### Step 2: Conditional Rules module

You could use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module in a custom rule (with a case/when construct), to display a Drupal message, based on whatever test you'd want to use to pick the random message to be shown.

With that all that's left for you is to think about which of the available tokens in your Rules Actions (triggered by Rules Event "After saving a new node", as in your question) is the most appropriate to make the result of that test random enough.